# spring social beans not registered in Spring 4.3.5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

I tried to update  from Spring 4.3.1 to Spring 4.3.8 today for our Spring MVC web application, which also uses Spring Social 1.1.4 and Java8 .
This failed at launch time with an error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'MySocialConfig': Unsatisfied
dependency expressed through method 'setSocialConfigurers' parameter   0; nested exception is 

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type '   java.util.List<org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigu rer>' available:  
 expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Updating as far as 4.3.4 was fine. But any version >= 4.3.5 fails at bean initialisation time  with this error.

And here is my Social Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class MySocialConfig extends SocialConfiguration implements SocialConfigurer {
      // some methods implemented according to SpringSocial docs:
   E.g. 

   @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {     
        configureXXX(cfConfig);   
        configureYYY(cfConfig); 
    } 
   }
```

Has anybody else encountered problems with @Configuration classes when updating to Spring 4.3.5 or later? Thanks 
Richard

Comment: I would say remove `extends SocialConfiguration` from your class. (that is already imported trough @EnableSocial and is basically redundant here). Or remove `@EnableSocial`. Problem is that you are injecting a bean into itself (the configuration needs the `SocialConfigurer`s but itself is a `SocialConfiguration`. Basically a cyclic dependency.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks for tip, I had no idea why it had broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You not need to extends SocialConfiguration(because you are using `@EnableSocial` it's used to add this annotation to an @Configuration class to have the Spring MVC configuration defined in SocialConfiguration imported.) instead of this you can extend SocialConfigurerAdapter ->

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig extends SocialConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {
        connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(new GitHubConnectionFactory(
                environment.getProperty("spring.social.github.appId"),
                environment.getProperty("spring.social.github.appSecret")));

        connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(
                environment.getProperty("spring.social.twitter.consumerKey"),
                environment.getProperty("spring.social.twitter.consumerSecret")));

        connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(new KakaoConnectionFactory(
                environment.getProperty("spring.social.kakao.appId")));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
        return repository;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInUtils providerSignInUtils(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
        return new ProviderSignInUtils(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/brant-hwang/spring-boot-social-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/axisj/examples/spring/social/SocialConfig.java) is nice example of spring social

Comment: Thanks - I was extending from SocialConfiguration as I wanted to override a method in it - but at least I nw know what causes the problem and I can look into removing the subclass dependency. You're right, if I remove  'extends SocialConfiguration' then I no longer see the unsatisfied dependency error. Thanks